# добавление input в angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть форма, состоит она из 2х элементов `<input type='button' value='add'>` и  `<input type='text'>`. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на `'add'` добавлялись поля ввода текста `<input type='text'>`. Думал это сделать с помощью `ng-repeat`, но ведь он срабатывает по факту загрузки страницы а не по нажатию кнопки, насколько я понимаю.. Еще как вариант на `'button'` навесить `ng-click`, а в контроллере в `$scope` прописать стандартный `document.createElement('input')`, но не уверен что это будет хороший вариант.

update:

когда мы добавили по клику несколько `<input type="text" ng-model="data" />`, к примеру 3. у них у всех один `ng-model`. У меня есть объект `ticket = { id : ticketId, name : $scope.name, description : $scope.description, photo : $scope.photo, time : $scope.time, stuff: $scope.stuff, }` в свойство `stuff` которого я должен внести данные этих 3х `input`. Но `stuff : $scope.data`, не выдает значения ни одного поля. При нажатии `<input type='button' ng-click='saveTicket()'>` данные со всех полей формы добавляются в ticket и сохраняются.

```
$scope.saveTicket = function () {
    var ticketId = new Date().getTime();
   ticket = {
        id : ticketId,
        name : $scope.name,
        description : $scope.description,
        photo : $scope.photo,
        time : $scope.time,
        stuff : $scope.stuff,
    };
    //$localStorage.ticket = ticket;
    localStorage.setItem(ticketId, JSON.stringify(ticket));
};
```

html:

```
<div class="form-inline cell col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="stuff">Ингредиенты</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-6" ng-repeat="input in inputSomething">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stuff" ng-model="input.stuff">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Код на добавление кнопки:

```
$scope.inputStuff = [];
$scope.addInput = function(){
    $scope.inputStuff.push({data:''})
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали? В чем проблема? В чем столкнулись?

Comment: @korytoff, оно то работает, просто я думаю что ангуляр предусматривает такие варианты, а document.createElement('input') это как-то слишком влоб чтоли..

Comment: Проблема то в чем, если у вас все работает?

Comment: @korytoff хочется сделать правильно, а не просто чтобы работало) поскольку я с ангуляром не так давно знаком, решил проконсультироваться

Comment: @Pavel, в следующий раз, стоит добавлять _как именно_ и _что именно_ вы уже пробовали.

Comment: @Grund, понял, спасибо, обязательно учту!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Храните в контроллере/скопе список данных, которые будете показывать в инпутах и отображайте его с помощью `ng-repeat`. По кнопке `add` просто добавляйте  еще один объект в список и все само перерисуется.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.inputs = [];
    this.add = function() {
      this.inputs.push({
        data: ""
      });
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as c">
  <div ng-repeat="el in c.inputs">
    <input type="text" ng-model="el.data" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="c.add()" />
  <pre>{{c.inputs | json:2}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pavel, обновите вопрос, добавив ваш код и описание что не получается

Comment: обновил вопрос...

Comment: @Pavel, добавьте в вопрос код, который у вас есть: html, js - чтобы было понятно, что и как вы делаете

Comment: отредактировал, html на бутстрап написан поэтому слишком объемный, но представляет с себя просто форму с `<input type="text">`, все данные успешно вытягиваются и записываются. Но вот с теми input что создались при нажатии 'add' проблема, данные с них не пишет в скоуп.

Comment: @Pavel, не нужен весь файл, только кусок где вы используете `ng-repeat` и `$scope.stuff` плюс код для функции add

Comment: @Pavel, вместо строчки `stuff : $scope.stuff,` используйте: `stuff : $scope.inputStuff`

Comment: я пробовал так но меня смущает то что он в итоге пишет в localstorage - `{"id":1456061386109,"stuff":[{"name":"","$$hashKey":"object:4","stuff":"dasdasda"},{"name":"","$$hashKey":"object:7","stuff":"asdasdadasd"}]}`, чтобы добраться нужно будет отдельно вытаскивать в каждом элементе массива данные, например `x[0].stuff`, `x[1].stuff`. Цикл нужно применять выходит?

Comment: @Pavel, ну если это разные элементы как вы к ним еще хотите обращаться? хотите чтобы было `stuf1stuf2stuf3`? в одной строке? как вы хотите с ними работать потом? или вы собираетесь их просто сохранять?

Comment: логично). Спасибо за помощь, этот способ действительно хорош!